# Why my goto command doing problems when compile?

Tags: c, goto

I coded a little program for math actions, but the `goto` command won't compile in some cases. Please help me.

Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define line11
#define YorN
#define End
#define Start

int main(void)
{
    float userNumber1,userNumber2;
    int mathAction;
    char tryAgain;
    Start:
    printf("Please write 2 numbers for your math action(a,b):\n");
    scanf("%f %f",&userNumber1,&userNumber2);
    Line11:
    printf("Please choose 1 of the following math actions by writing the action number :\n"
        "1)Adding a+b\n"
        "2)Subtracting a-b.\n"
        "3)Multiplying a*b.\n"
        "4)Dividing a/b.\n");
    scanf("%d",&mathAction);
    if (mathAction>4 || mathAction<1) //If the user pick something that's not 1-4 , then this if is going on.
    {
        printf("Grrrr.. pick between 1-4 ! \n");
        goto Line11;
    }
    if (mathAction==1)
    {
        printf("Adding %d + %d is %d\n",userNumber1,userNumber2,userNumber1+userNumber2);
    }
    if (mathAction==2)
    {
        printf("Subtracting %d - %d is %d\n",userNumber1,userNumber2,userNumber1-userNumber2);
    }
    if (mathAction==3)
    {
        printf("Multiplying %d * %d is %d\n",userNumber1,userNumber2,userNumber1*userNumber2);
    }
    if (mathAction==4)
    {
        if (userNumber2==0)
        {
            printf("You cant divide %d by 0 , its math error!\n");
            printf("Do you want to choose again? y/n\n");
            YorN:
            scanf("%c",&tryAgain)
            if (tryAgain !='y' || tryAgain !='n')
            {
                printf("Choose only yes or no by y for yes and n for no.");
                goto YorN;
            }
            if (tryAgain=='y')
            {
                goto Start;
            }
            if (tryAgain=='n')
            {
                goto End;
            }

        }
        printf("Dividing %d / %d is %.2f\n",userNumber1,userNumber2,userNumber1/userNumber2);
    }
    printf("Thanks for using my program !\nDo you want to try again? (Answer y/n)");
    scanf("%d",&tryAgain);
    if (tryAgain !='y' || tryAgain !='n')
    {
        printf("Choose only yes or no by y for yes and n for no.");
        goto YorN;
    }
    if (tryAgain=='y')
    {
        goto Start;
    }
    if (tryAgain=='n')
    {
        goto End;
    }
    End:
    system("PAUSE");
    return (0);
}
```

Here is the compile error:

```
q5.c: In function 'main':
q5.c:12:11: error: expected expression before ':' token
      Start:
           ^
q5.c:45:12: error: expected expression before ':' token
      YorN:
          ^
q5.c:69:15: error: expected identifier or '*' before ';' token
      goto YorN;
               ^
q5.c:73:16: error: expected identifier or '*' before ';' token
      goto Start;
                ^
q5.c:77:14: error: expected identifier or '*' before ';' token
      goto End;
              ^
q5.c:79:8: error: expected identifier or '*' before ';' token
     End:
        ^
```

I already tried everything to make this work, please help!
By the way, one of the `goto`s is actually working.

Comment: Show the code that demonstrates the problem in your post.

Comment: the code is too long so its not letting me put the whole code , please download and check it.

Comment: Try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem, and show that. And don't post images of text, especially *links* to images. A link may go stale and make your question worthless. If you have text, copy and paste it as text.

Comment: E.g `Start:` replace to `:` by `#define Start`

Comment: Oh and by the way there are very few things you need to use `goto` for. Try and avoid it at all cost.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Hmm, "try and avoid it at **all** cost" ... as you can always get along without `goto`, there cannot be "few things you need to use goto for"  (which is close to almost never in practise;-) I'd say "unless avoiding `goto` will make your code significantly less readable". There is just no rule of thumb when to use `goto`.

Comment: This code is so 1970ies style. Spaghetti should be on a plate with a good sauce, not on the monitor. Did you convert some old BASIC code? I'd recomment to restructure without `goto` first, C has loop constructs with `break` and `continue`, `else`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you have

```
#define YorN
#define End
#define Start
```

in the beginning of your source. These preprocessor macros will be evaluated before compiling into nothing, so this code:

```
YorN:
goto YorN;
```

will become

```
:
goto;
```

Just remove them, since it make no sense to have them.

Answer (score 0):

Don't `#define` your goto labels. Your code was also missing a semicolon ( after `scanf("%c",&tryAgain)` at label `YorN`).

[Here](http://codepad.org/X397ZkDm) you can see the corrected version.

For the sake of completeness, I'll post the corrected code here:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float userNumber1,userNumber2;
    int mathAction;
    char tryAgain;
     Start:
    printf("Please write 2 numbers for your math action(a,b):\n");
    scanf("%f %f",&userNumber1,&userNumber2);
    Line11:
    printf("Please choose 1 of the following math actions by writing the action number :\n"
     "1)Adding a+b\n"
     "2)Subtracting a-b.\n"
     "3)Multiplying a*b.\n"
     "4)Dividing a/b.\n");
    scanf("%d",&mathAction);
    if (mathAction>4 || mathAction<1) //If the user pick something that's not 1-4 , then this if is going on.
    {
        printf("Grrrr.. pick between 1-4 ! \n");
        goto Line11;
    }
    if (mathAction==1)
    {
        printf("Adding %d + %d is %d\n",userNumber1,userNumber2,userNumber1+userNumber2);
    }
    if (mathAction==2)
    {
        printf("Subtracting %d - %d is %d\n",userNumber1,userNumber2,userNumber1-userNumber2);
    }
    if (mathAction==3)
    {
        printf("Multiplying %d * %d is %d\n",userNumber1,userNumber2,userNumber1*userNumber2);
    }
    if (mathAction==4)
    {
        if (userNumber2==0)
        {
            printf("You cant divide %d by 0 , its math error!\n");
            printf("Do you want to choose again? y/n\n");
            YorN:
            scanf("%c",&tryAgain);
            if (tryAgain !='y' || tryAgain !='n')
            {
                printf("Choose only yes or no by y for yes and n for no.");
                goto YorN;
            }
            if (tryAgain=='y')
            {
                goto Start;
            }
            if (tryAgain=='n')
            {
                goto End;
            }

        }
        printf("Dividing %d / %d is %.2f\n",userNumber1,userNumber2,userNumber1/userNumber2);
    }
    printf("Thanks for using my program !\nDo you want to try again? (Answer y/n)");
    scanf("%d",&tryAgain);
    if (tryAgain !='y' || tryAgain !='n')
            {
                printf("Choose only yes or no by y for yes and n for no.");
                goto YorN;
            }
            if (tryAgain=='y')
            {
                goto Start;
            }
            if (tryAgain=='n')
            {
                goto End;
            }
 End:
 system("PAUSE");
 return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't compile because you have #defined the target symbols out of existence.

Other issues:
In most of your `printf()` format strings you use `%d` without care for the actual type of your argument. Either cast your objects to `int` or use the correct type (`%f` for `double`).

One final issue: for what you are doing, you should be using *functions* and *loops*. Every one of your gotos can be replaced with an appropriate loop.

Hope this helps.